# IEndpointRouteBuilder interface not found

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have

```
NuGet Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions
NuGet Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
```

and use the namespaces

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
```

I wanted to build something like this but it does not seem to know IEndpointConventionBuilder nor IEndpointRouteBuilder and refuses to compile.

```
public static class EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapServiceEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {

       //some code
    }
}
```

What am I missing...?

Comment: what is your .net core version? From seeing the documentation, it seems these packages are only .net core 3.0 or 3.1. if that's your version, i recommend dotnet restore, and make a clean build. also, you need to return something from that method, or it won't build either

Comment: @GlennvanAcker Yes, I have 3.1, I know I need to return something, that's not the point, the issue is I'm not getting the types

Comment: Can you verify that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder is in fact in one of those nuget packages? maybe try explicitly typing the namespace. edit: I checked, it should indeed be in that assembly, could it be that you don't have the correct version?

Comment: Yes it is there but one can't access it

Answer (score 23):

If you're creating an ASP.NET Core library, then you need to include the `FrameworkReference` in the project file as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET Core 3.0, you need to set the the Framework reference in you `csproj` file.

Change

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

To

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

See [Microsoft's migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference) for more information

Comment: But this makes the project into an actual web project, not a Class library.

Answer (score 1):

This [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) provides guidance for using ASP.NET Core APIs in a class library.

If your project is targeting ASP.NET Core, add the following `<FrameworkReference>` element to your project file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

So after some looking in the .net framework I found a work around and access the backing store in the builder

```
var endpointDataSource = app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(EndpointDataSource)) as EndpointDataSource;
```

After this you have all endpoints that have been configured as well as add your own.